# JS function is not defined. How to reference the function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, referenceerror, dropdownlistfor

In my mvc view I have a DropDownList that gets values from a dictionary

```
<div class="InputPart">
    @(Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(model => model.PasportAddressRegionID)
                    .Name("ddlfRegions1")
                    .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable<Dictionary>)ViewData["Regions"], "ID", "Title"))
                    .ClientEvents(e => e.OnChange("changeRegion1"))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-width:200px" }))
  </div>
```

and I have JS function **changeRegion1()** that gets these values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeRegion1() {
    var rgnId = $('#ddlfRegions1').data('tDropDownList').value();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("_GetDistrict", "Staffs"))',
        data: { regionId: rgnId },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            var combobox = $('#ddlfDistricts1').data('tDropDownList');
            combobox.dataBind(result);
            combobox.enable();
        }
    });
} </script>
```

I put the function in the same view, below all the code, but when run I got  **Uncaught ReferenceError: changeRegion1 is not defined**. The function itself is OK, but it seems to me that event handler does not see it here.
So I just wonder what is wrong here? And how should I reference the function?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the code is present on the page? If you look at the page source in the browser do you see it there?

Comment: @JJJ No, actually I cannot find this code on the page sourse, but it presents on the View. Hmm.. Do you have any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: @RinaMi Did you check console to check for any errors before your script is getting rendered?

Comment: SOLUTION: one smart guy suggested to move my function up to the beginning of my view and it WORKS now :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example for the Kendu UI Dropdown list Event handling for ASP.Net and MVC. Compare to your code. The example shows Events, you call ClientEvents otherwise looks ok.

http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/dropdownlist/overview

```
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("dropdownlist")
      .BindTo(new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" })
      .Events(e => e
            .Select("dropdownlist_select")
            .Change("dropdownlist_change")
      )
    )
    <script>
    function dropdownlist_select() {
        //Handle the select event.
    }

    function dropdownlist_change() {
        //Handle the change event.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this example uses Kendo().DropDownList() that is a litle bit different

Comment: @RinaMi My Apologies.